# Why are the responses to my Java questions on Stack Overflow decreasing?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I used to receive a lot more answers to my [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions last year and earlier this year. But I'm beginning to notice a decline in the number of responses I'm getting here on Stack Overflow. To some of my recent Java questions, I got no responses. Some got one response. No more though.

This is specific to Stack Overflow so I didn't post this question anywhere else because I feel this is the best place to figure out what's going on.

I'm assuming it may be because Java is getting old and there are fewer Java programmers using Stack Overflow. Or is it because my profile has bad ratings that I'm unaware of or something?

Comment: Absolutely not to hurt you, but just asking, are you making sure, your questions are _worthy_ of the time for the experts? (P.S - I don't know Java, I'm a C person, and the average answer rate is pretty good in my tag, IMHO)

Comment: I've just glanced through your questions... I see 2 with no answers at all that haven't been marked as dupe. In general, your questions ALL have 1 answer minimum, more than that on average. (and looking to your older questions, seems like it was always about the same average) Also, to get to the FIRST question without an accepted answer, I have to go to page 2 when sorting by newest question.... is this REALLY a problem? All your inquiries get an answer...

Comment: Could just be a numbers thing.  Like the proportion of answerers to askers in the java tag might be getting diluted by a lot of newer users.

Comment: Looking at your question history, your last 6 months of questions have at least 1 response, several with more than that, and all have an accepted answer. What are you talking about? Your claim that some of your recent questions "got 0 responses" is invalid. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1445444/horse-voice?tab=questions

Comment: the questions I'm asking are advanced questions. Or more specific to libraries rather. So I'm wondering it might be the specificity of my questions. Do you see anything wrong with my profile?

Comment: some of the answers I'm getting are from new comers and they are incorrect answers.

Comment: @HorseVoice Show examples. You are making a claim without backing it up. All your recent questions have accepted answers which would indicate that they are, in fact, correct instead. Are you accepting incorrect answers?

Comment: @HorseVoice I don't see a lot of your questions with unaccepted answers. If you accept bad answers, then maybe the problem is that people don't look at answered questions (and therefore you might not wanna throw that checkmark on bad answers?)

Comment: why am I getting downvotes on this question?

Comment: @HorseVoice voting is different on meta. I know I downvoted because I can't see proof of what you claim, so this kinda sounds like a rant. In any case you don't lose rep for downvotes on Meta, so don't fret.

Comment: @HorseVoice Because people disagree due to the fact that the claims you're making are baseless and all evidence points to the contrary.

Comment: Regardless of me really not seeing the problem you're describing (and that is probably the reason for downvotes): speaking from experience, its hard to find good Java questions in among the waterfall of duplicates / do my homework questions. The tag itself has reached a certain level of stagnation where most is duplicate, in my eyes.

Comment: Because, in it's current form, it's not a very useful question. What are we supposed to do based off of your entirely subjective anecdote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps:

- There aren't a lot of people interested or knowledgeable in the questions you ask (i.e. bikeshedding).
- Someone has satisfactorily answered the question and doesn't see a reason to add on to it.
- The people that could answer your question simply aren't online at a given point in time.

I answer **a lot** of Java questions, and this is probably the first time I've seen your username come up.  I wouldn't take offense to this or anything; be patient and you *may* wind up getting more answers to your questions.

Answer (score 21):

You have a question to answer ratio of nearly 10:1. I'd say that you may be part of the reason there aren't more answers... too many people asking and not answering creates an overwhelming number of unanswered questions for those of us who actually answer.

SO welcomes questions from the general community, which is why you can ask a question without needing to create an account. You have no mandate or responsibility to answer questions.

But if you are going to complain about the lack of good answers, then I suggest that you "be the change" and go answer some unanswered questions. It might free someone up to find and answer yours.